# Electron.remote.require('sqlite3') query performance 5x slower, callback 500x slower

Tags: webpack, electron, node-sqlite3

I'm using Electron w/ webpack and try to add `sqlite3` to the mix. See [stripped down test project](https://github.com/pamtbaau/electron-sqlite3)

I came accross two possible solutions.

1. When I `require('sqlite3')` in `index.html` and create a global variable referencing the database, I can query the db from within my application using the global variable. Performance is ok.

   Issues: Using global variable feels ugly and I cannot seem to configure Karma to use this scenario.

   Question: How should I configure Karma (tried both `files` and `customContextFile` options) to unit-test this scenario?
2. When I use `remote.require('sqlite3')` in my application, the database can be opened/created, but performance of queries degrade by factor ~10 and performance of results callback is down ~500x. (I guess it's a memory allocation issue)

   Issues: Sqlite is useless performancewise.

   Question: Why does this performance degradation occur and how to solve it to use all benefits of sqlite?

Btw. When using `import { Database } from 'sqlite'` with `const db = new Database()` node-gyp and node-pre-gyp throw issues which I haven't been able to solve.

NB. I have been using `sql.js` (performance issues) and `Lovefield` (inflexible IndexedDB store) as alternatives for sqlite3.

Comment: The reason `remote.require('sqlite3')` is so much slower is that it sets up a proxy for `sqlite3` on the renderer. Every function you call on that proxy is then just sent to the main process via `ipcRenderer.sendSync`. The renderer halts for the duration it takes to process that function call.

Comment: @RoyalBingBong That makes sense since the manual states `Returns any - The object returned by require(module) in the main process`. I didn't realise what the penalty would be of this proxy... Maybe I should keep sqlite3 in main and do icpMain/ipcRenderer myself and only sent query strings and receive bare rows.